# Is LESS transformation to CSS done client-side or server-side?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, less

In lots of articles about comparing `LESS/SASS`, there was a claim that `LESS` will be converted to `CSS` at the client side, using `JavaScript` code.

I've also found something called `LessTransform` in ASP.NET MVC which is used in bundling.

For example:

```
var bundle = new StyleBundle("~/Content/style").Include(
    "~/Content/myStyles.less");
bundle.Transforms.Add(new LessTransform());

bundles.Add(bundle);
```

**Question 1:** is it true that in this way `LESS` populating is getting done server-side?

Most of comparisons noticed that LESS is client side (as a weakness on performance) and SASS is better integrated with Ruby.

**Question 2:** Is it true that because of `LessTransform` LESS is a more straightforward option when using ASP.NET MVC 4.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, in your example the transform is server-side. It is possible to compile it client-side but with bundling this is not the case. When I say client-side I mean the browser and not all browsers support this (modern only).
2. I would agree that less has more support in asp.net mvc. 
   Especially with Visual Studio Web Essentials having support for less.

http://vswebessentials.com/features/less

I often use it for :

- .less to .css preview
- View output from a .less compile
- Extract variables/mixins

**Update**

It did support Sass but it was limited and removed May 5th 2013 release.

To prove that the .less is compiled on the server, if you add the following to a less file in the bundle (un-compiled):

```
@color: #4D926F;

#header {
  color: @color;
}
h2 {
  color: @color;
}
```

Then view the response coming back in the browser it is compiled to:

```
#header {
  color: #4d926f;
}
h2 {
  color: #4d926f;
}
```

[image: Compiled less]

Comment: Thanks, I just corrected the typo and changed the extension to `less`